# JpaRepository - delete records between two zoneDateTime in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use a native query in jpaRepository Spring boot to delete records between two dates(timestamp with zone time)

Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity(name = "Products")
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime delivery;

 }
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
    

    @Modifying
    void deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(@Param("id")Long Id, @Param("start")Instant instant1, @Param("end")Instant instant2);
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM product p WHERE p.id = :id and :start<=p.delivery <=:end ", nativeQuery = true)

}
```

my problem is How to convert my Instant Date to Timestamp with time zone and how to get example all record between this two date in date base : 2020-09-05 15:43:05.713424+02 and 2020-10-05 15:43:05.713424+02

How can i write a good native query to delete this

Comment: Why not just a JPQL and use the between keyword (which would work in SQL as well).

Answer (score 0):

in your service/controller class

```
Instant startInstant = ...
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(startInstant, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
// do the same thing for end datetime

// call productRepository bean
productRepository.deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(id, start, end);
```

and your repository method

```
void deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(@Param("id")Long Id, @Param("start")ZonedDateTime start, @Param("end")ZonedDateTime end);
```

in your native query

```
DELETE FROM product WHERE id = :id and (delivery BETWEEN :start AND :end)
```

Comment: Hi @bhimantoro suryo my problem in the delete native query is the delivery column is a timestamp with zon in the database and start and end are Instant. In your query , how can i convert start and end to timestamp with timestamp with zone europe paris. In database, the delivery column has this value 2020-04-13 03:00:16+02

Comment: you can convert it from instant to zoneddatetime and passed it through the repository method
`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(start, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))`

Comment: Hi @bhimantoro suryo
can you confirm me please , i have this query  : DELETE FROM product WHERE id = :id and (delivery BETWEEN ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(:start, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")) AND ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(:end, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")))

Comment: not like that, this code `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(start, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))` is used before call the `deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate` method

use this coversion in your service/controller class, and don't forget to change your repository method datatype from Instant to ZonedDateTime

Comment: @obela06 check my edited answer